# How can I use HTML elements in js before declaring it?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to make a 2D game with `HTML5` canvas.so what i have to do is define the canvas for `js`

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('gamecanvas');
```

When I put this sentence after the `<canvas>` tag, the code works very well. but when I put the script inside the `head` tag in a `script` tag(before writing the `<canvas>` tag, it gives me the error

```
ncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null
```

and this is because the canvas was not "declared" before the `js` code since `JS` reads the code line by line.

However, this [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Basic_usage) has written the code before writing the `canvas` tags. How could that happen.

One more question, why `JS` doesn't give any error when using a function before declaring it?shouldn't it be the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, this tutorial has written the code before writing the canvas tags. How could that happen.

It doesn't *run* the code until after the element has been added to the DOM.

The code is in a function. That function gets called in response to the `load` event.

> One more question, why JS doesn't give any error when using a function before declaring it?shouldn't it be the same?

Function declarations are subject to hoisting (which essentially means they are discovered at compile time instead of run time).

Answer (score 1):

Don't Execute code that references a DOM element until the page is ready. To call a function after the page is ready:

```
<body onload="doSomething()">
```

The function doSomething() can certainly appear on the page before the elements it references as long as the function is only executed after the elements are in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

I know about 3 solutions how to fix that problem. The easiest and propably best is (as someone above already wrote)

```
<body onload="doSomething()">
```

because html is loading code from the top of the page to the bottom, it's predictable that first will be loaded javascript, and his functions will do, what they have to do, finding the ID, but how, when the page wasn't still loaded. The onload function above will execute function you entered, after the whole body will be loaded.

Another way is put the `<script>` tag to the end of the page so javascript will be loaded as the last one.
Or if you are open to Jquery, the basic function of jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){ ... TO DO ...});
```

will do the same.